# How do I fix React Refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, react-native-web, react-refresh

I'm building a React app and I keep getting the same errors that I just can't fix:
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import *server*/reactweb/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

I have tried a symlink to no avail.  I'm really not sure what else to do here, guys.  Here's the code:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "acims",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.5",
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native": "^0.72.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1299.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.6",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start ./index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build ./index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

import React from 'react';

```
import React from 'react';

import WebRoutes from './src/WebRoutes';

export default function App() {
  return React.createElement(WebRoutes, null);
}
```

index.js (in my root directory)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './src/reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  React.createElement(React.StrictMode, null,
    React.createElement(App)
  )
);

reportWebVitals();
```

webpack.config.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/admin/SettingsScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/admin/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/auth/LoginScreen';
import ClientsScreen from './screens/contracts/ClientsScreen';
import ContractsScreen from './screens/contracts/ContractsScreen';
import ProspectsScreen from './screens/contracts/ProspectsScreen';
import SplashScreen from './screens/contracts/SplashScreen';
import TimeCardAdminScreen from './screens/time/TimeCardAdminScreen';
import TimeCardEmpScreen from './screens/time/TimeCardEmpScreen';
import MyTasksScreen from './screens/user/MyTasksScreen';


const WebRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/splash" element={<SplashScreen />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginScreen />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupScreen />} /> // Add this line
        <Route path="/clients" element={<ClientsScreen />} />
        <Route path="/prospects" element={<ProspectsScreen />} />
        <Route path="/contracts" element={<ContractsScreen />} />
        <Route path="/mytasks" element={<MyTasksScreen />} />
        <Route path="/settings" element={<SettingsScreen />} />
        <Route path="/timecard" element={<TimeCardEmpScreen />} />
        <Route path="/timecardadmin" element={<TimeCardAdminScreen />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default WebRoutes;
```

File Structure:

```
root
 |-build
 |-node_modules
 |-public
    |-index.html
 |-App.js
 |-index.js
 |-package.json
 |-src
    |-assets
    |-components
    |-constants
    |-screens
    |-utils
      |-runtime.js
    |-runtime.js //*yeah, I got it in there twice for testing*//
    |-WebRoutes.js
  |-App.css
  |-App.js
  |-babel.config.js
  |-index.css
  |-package-lock.json
  |-package.json
  |-webpack.config.js
```

I am trying to run `npm start build` and I expect the react app to mount and launch properly

Comment: You will need to retry the `npm install` steps, as the warning you're getting is telling you that react-refresh module is not being found _inside_ the node_modules directory in your app

Comment: Harrison, I wish I could count the number of times I've tried that lol.  I'm going to try a full deconstruct and a brand new create react app and see if that does it.  I have a feeling I may have overwritten or messed with some of the settings without knowing it.  I'll report back shortly.  Thanks for your help!